# Animate button background image on IsMouseOver in WPF/XAML/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Based on the code below, is it possible to animate the transition from `image1` to `image2` on button `IsMouseOver`event?

The following code works fine showing `image1` as the upstate image and `image2` as the hover image on a button but it does not animate the transition.

### XAML Style

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="button" CornerRadius="0" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">

                                <TextBlock  Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                                    <Setter TargetName="button"  Property="Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/App;component/Images/image2.png" Stretch="None"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
     </Style>
```

### Usage

```
        <Button x:Name="findRButton"
                Style="{StaticResource MainMenuButtonTemplate}" 
                Margin="0,0,0,0"  
                Height="53" 
                Command="{Binding FindrViewCommand}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/image1.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

Comment: It is possible but how would you want to animate the transition makes a difference to give you a solid answer.  I could post a fade out / in transitional animation but it may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: A fade or a murph animation would be more than fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that shows you how to do what you're looking for.

In order to use animations during triggers you must utilize the enter and exit actions of that trigger.  You must also name BeginStoryboard so that you can stop it in other calls.

Review the code and if you have anymore questions let me know.  This will fade from image1 to image2 and vice versa with mouse over / leave.

```
<Window x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="400"
        Width="500">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="mouseOverStoryboard"
                    Duration="00:00:00.5">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image1"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="0"
                             Duration="00:00:00.5" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image2"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="1"
                             Duration="00:00:00.5" />
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="mouseLeaveStoryboard"
                    Duration="00:00:00.5">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image1"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="1"
                             Duration="00:00:00.5" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image2"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="0"
                             Duration="00:00:00.5" />
        </Storyboard>

        <Style x:Key="MainMenuButtonStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Image x:Name="image1"
                                       Source="Images/image1.png" />
                                <Image x:Name="image2"
                                       Source="Images/image2.png"
                                       Opacity="0" />
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                         Value="True">
                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="mouseLeaveStoryboard" />
                                        <BeginStoryboard Name="mouseOverStoryboard"
                                                         Storyboard="{StaticResource mouseOverStoryboard}" />
                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="mouseOverStoryboard" />
                                        <BeginStoryboard Name="mouseLeaveStoryboard"
                                                         Storyboard="{StaticResource mouseLeaveStoryboard}" />
                                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MainMenuButtonStyle}"
                Width="120"
                Height="120" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @fs_tigre No problem; glad to help.

Comment: @ MichaelPuckettII  - Any idea why I get warning `Could not find a part of the path C:\Program Files\...` in the `Source` for the images in the style when inside a `UserControl`? It works fine when inside a `Window`. I know the images exist and the link is correct since it works when inside a `Window`.

Comment: Nevermind, adding `pack://application:` did the trick... `Source="pack://application:/Images/my-image.png"`. Thanks

Comment: FYI - I ended up using `Source="/AppName;component/Images/my-image.png"` since images were not visible at compile time when using `pack://application:`